# Can't get array

Tags: javascript, arrays, append

I'm kinda stuck as to why this isn't working.

The appends are working.  I've got all the anchors in the html, but for some reason I can grab that array with jquery.  I'm starting to wonder if it's because I added them with jquery.

this keeps alerting some, but really it shouldn't alert anything

```
               //$('#swiffy-braces-diagram').html("<img src='/assets/uploads/images/brace-painter.png'/>");
             $('#swiffy-braces-diagram').css('background-image', "url('/assets/uploads/images/brace-painter.png')")
                 .append("<a href='' id='elastic-tie'>")
                 .append("<a href='' id='loop-in-archwire'>")
                 .append("<a href='' id='archwire'>")
                 .append("<a href='' id='bracket'>")
                 .append("<a href='' id='headgear-tube'>")
                 .append("<a href='' id='coil-spring'>")
                 .append("<a href='' id='tie-wire'>")
                 .append("<a href='' id='band'>")
                 .append("<a href='' id='hook'>")
                 .append("<a href='' id='elastic'>")
                 .append("<div id='description'>");
             });

            if( $('#swiffy-braces-diagram a').length == 0){alert('some');}

            $('#swiffy-braces-diagram a').each( function(i){
                $(this).mouseover( function(){
                    $('#swiffy-braces-diagram #description').html( description[i] );
                });
            });
```

Comment: Are you sure `#swiffy-braces-diagram` exists?

Comment: Just fyi, you can put all those anchors into a single string and attach it with a single `append` call, that would be much more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Your code currently contains a syntax-error. When you say, the append() works, I guess you run that code inside an event-callback, e.g. ready.

When I'm right, use this:

```
jQuery(
  function($)
  {
    $('#swiffy-braces-diagram').css('background-image', "url('/assets/uploads/images/brace-painter.png')")
                 .append("<a href='' id='elastic-tie'>")
                 .append("<a href='' id='loop-in-archwire'>")
                 .append("<a href='' id='archwire'>")
                 .append("<a href='' id='bracket'>")
                 .append("<a href='' id='headgear-tube'>")
                 .append("<a href='' id='coil-spring'>")
                 .append("<a href='' id='tie-wire'>")
                 .append("<a href='' id='band'>")
                 .append("<a href='' id='hook'>")
                 .append("<a href='' id='elastic'>")
                 .append("<div id='description'>");

                  // }); <--this has been removed


            if( $('#swiffy-braces-diagram a').length == 0){alert('some');}

            $('#swiffy-braces-diagram a').each( function(i){
                $(this).mouseover( function(){
                    $('#swiffy-braces-diagram #description').html( description[i] );
                });
            });
        });//<--the removed brackets now are here
```

Note that I did remove the  `});` after the append().

Without that, you will leave the ready-function right there, the rest of the script will be executed **before** you append() all these elements.

Answer (score 1):

`"<a href='' id='elastic-tie'>"` is not a valid piece of HTML.  You need the closing `</a>` tag and presumably, you want some content in the links too.

Plus without any content in the links, they don't occupy any space on the page so you will never get a mouseover event on them.